# The Fonts \large and \normalfont (not \normalsize) are Strikingly Similar. Is There a Difference?

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I have noticed that the fonts `\large` and `\normalfont` seem to be strikingly similar.

For instance, consider

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\large
{\Huge{\textcolor{blue}{large}}} \\[15pt]
\lipsum[2]
\vskip 25pt
\normalfont
{\Huge{\textcolor{blue}{normalfont}}} \\[15pt]
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

with the output

[image]

Inspecting the output, it would seem that there is no difference between `\large` and `\normalfont`.

However, it stands to reason that there must be some difference between the two.

**Question:** Can someone apprise me of the difference(s) between the two said fonts; and, under what circumstances might one be preferred over the other?

Comment: The command `\normalfont` does not change the fontsize. Test it with the command `\normalsize`.

Comment: @uli Thank you for your comment. I now understand it. Please consider presenting it as an answer---as it is an appropriate response to the question posed. Also, an explanation as to why or when one would use `\normalfont` would be much appreciated; for,  as you said, it does not change the fontsize. In fine, if I use, say, `\Huge` followed by `\normalfont`---then `\normalfont`  will be Huge. A posted answer to this type might also help to alleviate confusion between `\normalsize` and `\normalfont`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

**Update 1:** Turns out the OP simply confused two commands that look similar (normalfont vs. normalsize) and my brain auto-corrected this and answered the more obvious question (to me).

**Update 2:** The OP mentioned in a comment that he/she wants to know more about the `\normalfont` command. According to [Overleaf](https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_sizes), you can summarize it as follows: *"If you want to go back to **"normal" font style (default for the LaTeX class you are using)**, this can be done by using the `\textnormal{...}` command or the `\normalfont` switch command."* (**bold** formatting my me) **Remark:** A "switch command" is also referred to as a "declaration".

---

***(Original Answer)***

Here is a maybe better code example, in addition, have a look at [here](https://www.sascha-frank.com/latex-font-size.html).

[image]

*(Changes in font size depending on the selected standard font size (article, report, book, and letter). Taken from [here](https://www.sascha-frank.com/latex-font-size.html).)*

| `\documentclass[X]{...}` | X=10pt | X=11pt | X=12pt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `\tiny` | 5pt | 6pt | 6pt |
| `\scriptsize` | 7pt | 8pt | 8pt |
| `\footnotesize` | 8pt | 9pt | 10pt |
| `\small` | 9pt | 10pt | 11pt |
| `\normalsize` | 10pt | 11pt | 12pt |
| `\large` | 12pt | 12pt | 14pt |
| `\Large` | 14pt | 14pt | 17pt |
| `\LARGE` | 17pt | 17pt | 20pt |
| `\huge` | 20pt | 20pt | 25pt |
| `\Huge` | 25pt | 25pt | 25pt |

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item {\Huge Huge {\normalsize (Huge)}}
    \item {\huge huge {\normalsize (huge)}}
    \item {\LARGE LARGE {\normalsize (LARGE)}}
    \item {\Large Large {\normalsize (Large)}}
    \item {\large large {\normalsize (large)}}
    \item {\normalsize normalsize {\normalsize (normalsize)}}
    \item {\small small {\normalsize (small)}}
    \item {\footnotesize footnotesize {\normalsize (footnotesize)}}
    \item {\scriptsize scriptsize {\normalsize (scriptsize)}}
    \item {\tiny tiny {\normalsize (tiny)}}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \fbox{\Huge Huge {\normalsize Huge}}
    \item \fbox{\huge huge {\normalsize huge}}
    \item \fbox{\LARGE LARGE {\normalsize LARGE}}
    \item \fbox{\Large Large {\normalsize Large}}
    \item \fbox{\large large {\normalsize large}}
    \item \fbox{\normalsize normalsize {\normalsize normalsize}}
    \item \fbox{\small small {\normalsize small}}
    \item \fbox{\footnotesize footnotesize {\normalsize footnotesize}}
    \item \fbox{\scriptsize scriptsize {\normalsize scriptsize}}
    \item \fbox{\tiny tiny {\normalsize tiny}}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: This post is my first post using [tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997).

Comment: it would probably be clearer to use `{\normalsize` rather than `\normalsize{` in all cases to avoid giving the impression that `\normalsize` takes an argument, even though the output is the same here as you are at teh end of the outer group in all cases.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Agreed! I won't be able to correct it anytime soon, I am on my phone atm

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the helpful edit.